# For UDP broadcast gurus: Problems achieving high-bandwidth audio UDP broadcast over WiFi (802.11N and 802.11G)

Tags: udp, wifi, bandwidth, broadcast, subnet

I'm attempting to send multichannel audio over WiFi from one server to multiple client computers using UDP broadcast on a private network.

I'm using software called Pure Data, with a UDP broadcast tool called netsend~ and netreceive~.  The code is here:
http://www.remu.fr/sound-delta/netsend~/

To cut a long story short, I'm able to achieve sending 9 channels to one client computer in a point-to-point network, but when I try to do broadcast to 2 clients (haven't yet tried more), I get no sound.  I can compress the audio and send 4 channels compressed (about 10% size of uncompressed) over UDP broadcast to 2 clients successfully.  Or I can send 1 channel over UDP broadcast to 2 clients, with some glitches.

The WiFi router is a Linksys WRT300N.  All computers are running Windows XP.  The IP addresses are 192.168.1.x, with subnet mask 255.255.255.0 and the subnet broadcast address: 192.168.1.255.

I'm curious - what happens to UDP broadcast packets in the router?
If I have a subnet mask of 255.255.255.0, then does the router make 254 packets for every packet sent ot the broadcast address?

My WiFi bandwidth is at least 100Mbps, but I can't seem to send audio of more than around 10Mbps over UDP broadcast to multiple clients.

What's stopping me from sending audio up to the bandwidth limit of the WiFi?

any suggestions for socket code modifications, network setups, router setups, subnet modifications...  all very much appreciated!

thanks
Nick

Comment: See also this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1736042

Comment: are you able to set up your workstation as the access point?

Answer (score 7):

Your problem is caused by the access point's rate control algorithm. With unicast the access point tracks what data rate every particular receiver can reliably receive at, and sends about that rate. With multicast the access point does not know which receivers are interested in the data, so simple access points send the data at the slowest possible rate (1Mb/s). Better implemented access points may send the data at the rate that the slowest connected client is using, and the best access points use IGMP snooping to see who's receiving each IP multicast stream, and they will choose the slowest rate out of the receivers for that stream.

The simplest solution is to not use multicast when you have a small number of WiFi receivers.

Answer (score 3):

Are all parties connected via WiFi or is the sender using a
wired connection to the Access Point? Broadcast data will
be transmitted as unicast data from a station to an access
point and the access point will then retransmit the data
as broadcast/multicast traffic so it will use twice the
on-air bandwidth compared to when the sender sits on the
wired side of the AP.

When sending a unicast frame the AP will wait for an ACK
from the receiving station and it will retransmit the
frame until the ACK arrives (or it times out). Broadcast/multicast
frames are not ACKed and therefore not retransmitted.
If you have a busy/noisy radio environment this will
cause the likelyhood of dropped packets to increase,
potentially a lot, for multicast traffic compared to unicast
traffic. In an audio application this could certainly be audible.

Also, IIRC, broadcast/multicast traffic does not use the
RTS/CTS procedure for reserving the media which exarbates
the dropped packets problem.

It could actually be the case that multiple unicast streams
work better than a single multicast stream under less-than-ideal
radio conditions given that the aggregated bandwidth is
high enough.

If you can I would suggest that you use wireshark to sniff
the WiFi traffic and take a look at the destination address
in the 802.11 header. Then you can verify if the packets
are actually broadcast or not over the air.

Answer (score 1):

Your design is failing due to a common misconception with WiFi speeds.  With 802.11n the number 300mb/s is the link speed, not the actual bandwidth available for user data or even the IP layer.  The effective bandwidth is closer to 40mb/s best case, have a look at the FAQ on SmallNetBuilder.com that discusses this in further detail.

http://www.smallnetbuilder.com/wireless/wireless-basics/31083-smallnetbuilders-wireless-faq-the-essentials

Answer (score 0):

> I'm curious - what happens to UDP broadcast packets in the router? If I have a subnet mask of 255.255.255.0, then does the router make 254 packets for every packet sent ot the broadcast address?

No the "router" doesn't make 254 individual packets. Furthermore, I suspect the protocol leverages "multicast" addresses rather than using a "broadcast" address.

Since broadcast/multicast traffic can easily be misused, there are many networking equipment that limit/block by default such traffic. Of course, some essential protocols (e.g. ARP, DHCP) rely on broadcast/multicast addresses to function and won't be blocked by default.

Hence, it might be a good thing to check for multicast/broadcast control knobs on your router.

Comment: I've looked through everything in the router, and didn't find much that could help.  The WRT300N interface is actually viewable here: http://ui.linksys.com/files/WRT300N/0.93.9/  
I was wondering if it might help to reduce my subnet mask to 255.255.255.240 or something like that - would that reduce traffic?

Comment: If the software is actually using a Multicast address to send traffic to multiple Clients, changing the subnet mask will have no effect: Multicasting doesn't rely on this configuration parameter.

Comment: The first to do IMO is to determine if the software is actually using Multicasting before proceeding to another step.